# Unexpected GROUP BY behavior MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have a table `Quotes` with data like

```
id  number    revision    status      amount
============================================
1    6681         1       Open       1000.00
2    6681         2       Open       5421.00
3    6681         3       Open       1246.12
4    6681         4       Received   8444.12
5    1251         1       Open        412.42
```

The important thing to note is that each quote can have multiple revisions, with different amounts and other info.

I have a table with a `SELECT` query where one of the options is to only see the latest revision of each quote.  I had tried to accomplishing that with a group text.

The normal query is

```
SELECT
number, revision, status, amount
FROM quotes
ORDER BY id DESC
```

And my `GROUP BY` version is

```
SELECT
number, MAX(revision) as `revision`, status, amount
FROM quotes
GROUP BY number
ORDER BY id DESC
```

I thought this group by would select the top revision of each group of numbers, but instead its mix and matching and I get this

```
number    revision    status    amount
=======================================
6681         4         Open      1000.00
```

I get the right number and revision, but the status says Open, and the amount is the amount from Revision 1, not the 4th revision.  Any idea what is wrong with my syntax here?

Comment: When you use `GROUP BY` you should always list all non-aggeregated columns used in `SELECT` in the `GROUP BY`. In your case correct format would be `GROUP BY number, status, amount`. Omitting columns will cause incorrect results. But as you want the `MAX(revision)` over the `number` and you are using MySQL 5.6, you need to use subquery as answered by Sebastian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following, using a sub-query to get the last revisions of the quotes. You can `INNER JOIN` this sub-query with your table to get the full row of the latest revision per group (`number`):

```
SELECT quotes.* 
FROM quotes INNER JOIN (
  SELECT number, MAX(revision) AS revision
  FROM quotes
  GROUP BY number
) max_quotes ON quotes.number = max_quotes.number AND quotes.revision = max_quotes.revision
ORDER BY id DESC
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0056c8b9ed7dafc4accf6bfc0142171d)